# How to flatten a loop through the upper triangle of a matrix?

Tags: c++, loops, openmp

I have a situation where I am using openMP for the Xeon Phi Coprocessor, and I have an opportunity to parallelize an "embarrassingly parallel" double for loop.

However, the for loop is looping through the upper triangle (including the diagonal):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     // access some arrays with the value of i
     for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
         // do some stuff with the values of j and i
```

---

So, I've got the total size of the loop,

```
for (int q = 0; q < ((n*n - n)/2)+n; q++)
    // Do stuff
```

But where I am struggling is:

**How** do I calculate **i** and **j** from **q**?  Is it possible?

---

In the meantime, I'm just doing the full matrix, calculating i and j from there, and only doing my stuff when j >= i...but that still leaves a hefty amount of thread overhead.

Comment: The question is if computing i and j, e.g. involving integer square root, adds too much overhead. Then it might be faster to just process the whole matrix and skip the lower triangle part.

Comment: manually track i and j within this loop?

Comment: that is difficult, since, when parallelizing, each iteration could be worked on at any time...

Comment: What are representative values of `n`?

Comment: OK, I have to go elsewhere, but the main idea I had to do this relatively efficiently without precomputation was to calculate an approximate average row size before the point of `q`. The code I coughed up didn't give entirely correct run lengths but in the direction of correct. Someone might follow this and post a correct implementation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf nice, thanks man.

Comment: My open mp experience is limited to some toy programs. I am surprised that you cannot properly parallelize a doubly nested loop using open mp constructs and need to flatten it. Could you briefly explain what goes wrong if you rely on open mp constructs for parallelizing the loop?

Comment: To parallelize a 2-level nested loop, just add `collapse(2)` to the `omp for` clause: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-collapse-directive

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  the key is that I am writing for a Xeon Phi Coprocessor, which has 240 threads and 512 width SIMD vectorization.  If I want the auto-vectorizor to work in intel's compiler, with max thread use, then I need to flatten the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I restate your problem, to find `i` and `j` from `q`, you need the greatest `i` such that

```
    q >= i*n - (i-1)*i/2
```

to define `j` as

```
    j = i + (q - i*n - (i-1)*i/2)
```

If you have such a greatest `i`, then

```
    (i+1)*n - i*(i+1)/2 > q                             >= i*n - (i-1)*i/2
     n-i                > (q - i*n - (i-1)*i/2)         >= 0
     n                  > j = i + (q - i*n - (i-1)*i/2) >= i
```

Here is a first iterative method to find i:

```
    for (i = 0; q >= i*n - (i-1)*i/2; ++i);
    i = i-1;
```

If you iterate over `q`, the computation of `i` is likely to exploit the iterative process.

A second method could use sqrt since

```
    i*n - i²/2 + i/2 ~ q
    i²/2 - i(n+1/2) + q ~ 0
    delta = (n+0.5)² - 2q
    i ~ (n+0.5) - sqrt(delta)
```

`i` could be defined as `floor((n+0.5) - sqrt((n+0.5)² - 2q))`

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't an answer as far as I can tell.  But, it is a workaround (for now).

I was thinking about it, and creating an array (or corresponding pointer), `a[(n*n + n)/2 + n][2]`, and reading in the corresponding `i` and `j` values in my calling code, and passing this to my function would allow for the speed up.

Comment: Although this isn't pretty, I think it might be the fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your loop to iterate as it is iterating on the whole matrix.
And just to keep track on your current line and each time you are entering a new line increment the index with the value of that line.

Then: `i == line` and `j == i%n`.

See this code:

```
int main() {

    int n = 10;
    int line = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n*n; i++){
        if (i%n == 0 && i!=0){
            line++;
            i += line;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "("<<line<<","<<i%n<<")";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Running Example](https://ideone.com/hB0kCU)

Comment: But does that parallelize easily?